# TFS and golang continuous Integration

Tags: go, tfs, tfsbuild

I'm tracking the files of my `golang app` in a local `TFS server` integrated with `git`. I want to define `build`, `test`, and `deploy` steps but I can't find any tool for that.

How can I define a `build` and `test` step for the project that shows the `test results` in the `Team's web site`? thank you.

Comment: How to define build, test, and deploy steps? Could you explain more clearly? And which test are you using? If you just want to show the test results in the team's web site? Take a  look at the dashboard, did this meet your needs？ https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/report/overview

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT:I mean how should I setup tfs to build my app and run my Unit/Integration tests and then how can I see the test results / successful or failed builds ....

Comment: How do you build and run the test on your local machine?

Comment: @Eddie: I use command line.

Comment: What's the TFS version you use? TFS2015?

Comment: @Eddie: 2017 Update 1 x64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the vNext build system in TFS2017 and add Command Line task in the build definition to run the build and test just like what you do on local machine:
[image]
And then add a "Publish Test Result" task to publish the test result to TFS so that you can check the test result from the TFS Website. A limitation is that "Publish Test Result" task only support four Test Result Format for now: JUnit, NUnit, VSTest and XUnit.

Comment: Thank you I'm trying it,but It's a pain in the neck to install all dependencies via a batch file. sometimes I might need to copy some dependencies from my local machine.Can I build the source and run tests in a docker file and publish the results !!??Or is there a more convenient tool for doing it?

Comment: @Mohsen You can try with this extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscs-rm.docker